# Landmark on a detected object to determine whether it is right side up or not to determine correct rotation

Tags: python, c++, opencv, rotation

[Image of part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwD1Q.png)

Problem: If hole in the object if it is above or below the horizontal axis it will give me the correct rotation. It gives me the correct rotation now but I want it to know that relative to the hole it will give me positive or negative coordinates.

It does recognize the hole, but how do I make it known for the rotation to have correctly positive or negative degrees?

Thanks,

J

Comment: if you already have the coordinate of the hole, just compare the y-coordinate of the center point and the hole to determine positive or negative degree.

Comment: Well now its filtering through all of the found contours to find each one corresponding with the center of each part. So the current contours found are set between user defined parameters of an area. Now I'm trying to do it again but using a much smaller area and the same data set the first filter nly draws the contours of the object. Now I want to do the same thing but to the center and have it correspond to each part again just a hole on the object.  Does that make sense? Any ideas?